Tangent vectors to regular curve at constant angle to a fixed vector
Problem: Show that the tangent vectors to the regular curve $x(t)=(3t,3t^2,2t^3)$ make a constant angle ($\theta$) with the vector $a:=(1,0,1)$.
We have $b:=x'(t)=(3,6t,6t^2)$. I worked out that $b\cdot a = 3+6t^2$ (where $\cdot$ is the standard dot product in $\mathbb{R}^3$), $||a||=\sqrt{2}$, and $||b||=3\sqrt{1+4t^2+4t^4}$. After a bunch of reduction I get that $\frac{a\cdot b}{||a||\,||b||} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}t^2$.
Now we can apply the formula $\cos(\theta)=\frac{a\cdot b}{||a||\,||b||}$ to get $\theta = \arccos(\frac{a\cdot b}{||a||\,||b||}) = \arccos(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}t^2)$. This certainly doesn't appear to be constant.
Where might I have gone wrong here? I'd like to know if I screwed up the algebra or if I'm missing a bigger idea.

Somewhere you made a mistake. Since $|a|$ is constant it is enough to show
that
$$
\frac{(a\cdot b)^2}{|b|^2}
$$
is constant and that is
$$
\frac{(3+6t^2)^2}{9(1+4t^2+4t^4)}=\frac{9+36t^2+36t^4}{9(1+4t^2+4t^4)}=1,.
$$
